# Windows server RDP logon causes external USB disks to spin up

Tags: hard-drive, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a silent low power consumption Windows Server 2012 R2 machine with one SSD and two external USB 3.0 HDDs Toshiba Canvio Basics.

Those HDDs are the "green" ones and spin up for approximately 2 minutes if data needs to be read/written. I deliberately chose them as the data storage because of low power consumption, hot swap possibility and cheapness and won't use other disks.

Now here is the problem:

When I log into this server via RDP, these drives spin up even though I'm not reading or writing from them. Excessive spinups will kill them sooner as expected.

If I don't log out and just disconnect the RDP connection and leave the user session open, those drives won't spin up on the next logon.

Autorun is empty both in start menu and registry for current user and all users.

How to prevent the unnecessary spinup at logon? These drives need to be always connected because server should work in unattended mode, without physical access to the server.

Probably it is the Windows Explorer that enumerates disks at first run.